# Search multiple database columns using one search box

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I was wondering what the best approach would be to search a database via multiple columns by using only 1 search box. Scenario below:

I want to be able to search Customers by inputting their details into a search box. This could be either their name, post code or id. I can also perform 1 search by using more than 1 search  criteria. For example I could search by name and id (Bob Smith cus345).

A first approach I took was to split the search term, seperating each space into a seperate word but this has its down fall as a customer name may contain 3-4 words. This can lead to a tonne of conditional statements but this is inefficient so I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this.

I find this a difficult task to do because the user could search in any order (ie search by post code, then name and then id, or name and id and so forth)

Comment: We have a similar searching need and have found that using a stored procedure is much faster and easier to implement.

Comment: Ok, how would you then link the stored procedure to the post event of the search button in asp.net mvc3

Comment: How big is your table? How many rows? Is this actually a performance problem or do you only assume that? I think as long as you are under 100k rows you are pretty safe with just doing a table scan.

Comment: The table is very big, it contains a few thousand customers, what do you mean by "table scan"?

Comment: This however is not a scalable solution. As the data grows in size, the query will slow. The more complex the query the slower it will perform and also the more searches the more of a load on your application/server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to detect specific terms like post codes but you are right in saying that either way you will end up with a load of conditions.

I would highly recommend using Lucene.net. It is not difficult to implement but it provides ranked results by default, is lightning fast (faster than a stored proc would be against a multi-termed query) and will cater easily for the kind of search you are describing. You can also weight/bias certain fields, so a partial post code match has more weight than a first name match.

With regards to splitting a search, I usually run a check for reserved characters like * and (, or even strip them out completely if I don't want the user to be able to perform complex searches themselves. I then split upon word boundarys and perform a AND search.

As far as I know there is also a Lucene to Linq provider too.

Comment: Lucene.NET seems to be searching documents and not databases? Unless I'm wrong?

Comment: Almost. You would not use Lucene to search your database, however you would build a Lucene index based upon content in the db for example all customer names, post codes and customer IDs. When you search upon the index it is designed to be extremely efficient at query against this type of data pulling out ranked results. From a page of results, e.g. 10 customers, you could then hit the database with a select for those records.

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks for your response, I'll give it a try tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I used [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) on a project with similar requirements, just instead of EF, I was using linq to sql, but I'm confident the specific full text search functions can be mapped, via table functions, with EF.